# Python 3.6 Spyder IDE from Anaconda

Tags: python, ide, anaconda, python-3.6, spyder

How to open **spyder.exe** IDE after installing *Anaconda 5.2* in **Windows 64 bit** for running *Python 3.6 version*?

Comment: what does it have to do with computer science tag?

Answer (score 1):

Run `spyder` in the command prompt